# ¿Se puede modificar el código recibido por una página de terceros?

Tags: html, enlace, datos, modificaciones

Se puede pedir el código de una página de terceros y una vez recibido el código editarle cosas a este mismo?
Ejemplo:
En el siguiente código se envía un form a la página de terceros. La idea sería poder editar la página a la que se redirecciona posteriormente (Tomar solo unos datos del código recibido).

````
<html>
</head>
<body class="login">
<div id="login">
  <form action="http://www.megatarjeta.com.co/index/error" method="post" name="login" onSubmit="javascript:return submitLogin();">
    
    <div class="caja">
      <p> CONSULTE EL SALDO DE SU TARJETA </p>
      <input class="texto numerico" name="tarjeta" id="tarjeta" size="10" maxlength="10" type="text" placeholder=" Número de Tarjeta">
      <!--<input class="texto numerico" name="usuario" type="text" value="Ingrese Numero de Tarjeta" onfocus="if(this.value=='Ingrese Numero de Tarjeta')this.value=''">-->
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <input class="boton boton1" name="" type="submit" value="Consultar">
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Inicial" value=1> 
   
                </div>  
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </form>

</body> 

</head>

</html>```
````

Comment: Explica a que te refieres por "codigo", lo que veo en tu HTML es un form que sirve para enviar "datos"

Comment: me refiero a todo el código fuente de la página a la que nos redirige el form

Comment: Quieres modificar una página a la que no tienes acceso y no eres el propietario intelectual de ese desarrollo?

Comment: más bien tomar datos arrojados por la página y ponerlos en la mía. Usar la página como una calculadora, enviarle 2 + 2 y que su respuesta [4] pueda tomarla y ponerla en un apartado de mi página.